# How to replace content of post classList to Textarea ? Pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have posts, and I have added an edit button if the user logged in is the owner of the post,
How can I edit the content on my posts when I click on the edit button?

My posts are classList which has Childs (Divs) of the content.

I didn't learn frameworks yet so I'm trying to do this with Pure JavaScript.

index.js

```
function build_post(post){
        // create new div for each thing that needs to be shown
        current_logged_in_user = document.querySelector('#user_detail').value;
        const element = document.createElement('div');
        const post_username = document.createElement('div');
        const post_description = document.createElement('div');
        const post_date_added = document.createElement('div');
        const post_likes = document.createElement('div');
        // add the text for each div
        post_username.innerHTML = 'Username: ' + post.poster;
        post_description.innerHTML = 'Content: ' + post.description;
        post_date_added.innerHTML = 'Date: ' + post.date_added;
        post_likes.innerHTML = 'Likes: ' + post.likes;
        // append all divs to display-post
        element.appendChild(post_username);
        element.appendChild(post_description);
        element.appendChild(post_date_added);
        element.appendChild(post_likes);
        element.classList.add('element');
        console.log(element);
        post_username.addEventListener('click', function() {
            load_user_info(post.poster);
            load_user_posts(post.poster);
          });
          if (current_logged_in_user == post.poster){
            const edit_button = document.createElement('button');
            edit_button.innerHTML += 'Edit'
            element.appendChild(edit_button);
            edit_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
                edit_element(element);
            });
        }
        document.querySelector('#show-posts').appendChild(element)
}

function edit_element(element_to_edit){

}
```

HTML if relevant

```
<div id="page-view"></div>

<div id="load-profile">
    <div id="user-profile">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="posts-view">
    <h2>All Posts</h2>
    <form id="post-form">
<!--        {% csrf_token %}-->
        <h4>New Post</h4>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="post-body" placeholder="Post"></textarea>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Post">
    </form>
</div>

<div id ="show-posts"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change the Text-field to an Input with the value of the Text of the Post if the user is the owner of the post.
Where do you save the values? mysql?

Comment: I am using sqlite, do you mean like the form when I submit a post ?

Comment: Yes. Do you save the content in sqlite? You read the content of the posts, if you want to show the posts and if the user is the owner of the post, he can click "edit", and in the Textarea there should be the Text of his Post. Right? The value of the Textarea should be the text of the post.

Comment: That right, made me realize I was trying to replace the whole element but I had only to replace the "description" of the post only, I'm trying to make a fetch method to my views to update the textarea value now.